# What is the difference of lifetimes of compound types and scalar types?

Tags: python, variables, python-2.7

The following is an except from a tutorial.

---

**The default value is evaluated only once.** This makes a difference when the default is a mutable object such as a list, dictionary, or instances of most classes. For example, the following function accumulates the arguments passed to it on subsequent calls:

```
def f(a, L=[]):
    L.append(a)
    return L

print f(1)
print f(2)
print f(3)
```

This will print

```
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
```

---

However, when I try this with a scalar variable:

```
>>> def acu(n, a = 0):
    "Test if local variables in functions have static duration"
    a = a + n
    return a


>>> acu (5)
5
>>> acu (5)
5
```

---

*So why is this difference between the lifetimes of L and a?*

Comment: There is a huge difference with your two tests, one calls a mutating method on an object, and one rebinds a local name, nothing to do with compound/scalar

Comment: @ jamylak, please edit the title of the question if you deem reasonable. This is my second day of Python-ing and the silly questions are sure to come!

Comment: to make the tests equivalent, you could replace `L.append(a)` with `L = L + [a]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference. In the second part you are rebinding the local name `a`, not mutating the object it points to.